# CSS (JS) позиционирование HTML объектов

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, позиционирование

Итак, есть объект - div, который очень хотелось бы разместить **по центру видимой области**. Уточняю - по центру той зоны, куда смотрит пользователь по верх всех объектов что имеются.
Со вторым я справился - поставил `position: absolute;` да и всё. А вот как сделать центрирование да перемещение в видимую зону сказать затрудняюсь.
Пробовал использовать `hv`, но увы считает от начала да еще и только то, что я вижу - **не до места куда я вижу** что не удивительно. Поэтому, возможно стоит использовать JS чтобы реализовать задачу? Что можете сказать дорогие господа?

Comment: `z-index: 100;`

Comment: @Bulson Объект создается и видимый, но стоит сверху. А необходимо его сдвинуть оттуда.

Comment: https://youtu.be/qJVVZYTYA9U?list=PL4-IK0AVhVjPxS9a6wkX6I6zw4AHQyNfb&t=105

Comment: @Bulson увы мне не нужно вертикальное центрирование. Мне нужно перемещать объект в видимую область.

Answer (score 0):

Сложно понять в чем конкретно ваша проблема. Попробуйте поставить position: fixed и z-index: *тут должна быть цифра больше самого максимального значения, если нет поставьте 99*. Центрирование задается за счет выставление позиции на 0, и автоматического отступа(не обязательно именно так)

```
    .container {
      position:fixed;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: auto;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background: white;
      z-index:99;
   }
```

Если ваш объект для центрирования находится в родителе, можете отцентрировать через свойства    `flex`.

```
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
```